# ChartJS disappears after animating on when loaded through Animate CC HTML5 project

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, animate-cc

I am trying to integrate ChartJS into an Adobe Animate CC HTML5 project. Code works initially, but chart disappears once it finishes animating on. How do I get it to stay put?

See it in action here:
http://devenjames.com/cni/disappearing_chart.html

files are located here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gkcRyV5rdPiTQbz-KEDth0bsaoDiJ611/view?usp=sharing

I am a novice at best trying to hack my way through this coding project. Used to use Actionscript, now trying to use Javascript in Animate CC (aka New Flash). Any help is most appreciated! Thanks!